# AS3: Sandbox violation when trying to load an off-site swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, sandbox

I'm trying to load an swf placed on Amazon S3 (b.com) into an swf on a different domain (a.com), and it throws this error

```
SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content:http://www.a.com/loader.swf cannot accesshttp://b.com/loadee.swf. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
at flash.display::Loader/get content()
```

Both a.com and b.com have a crossdomain.xml on their root that looks like

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The swf I'm trying to load (b.com/loadee.swf) has been generated by software, so I can't add Security.allowDomain("*") to it or anything like that.

Can I load this swf in some way, or am I stuck using a.com to host everything? I also want loader.swf and loadee.swf to be able to communicate (pass vars and make function calls)
if that's possible. This is what I have in loader.swf

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://b.com/crossdomain.xml");
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://b.com/loadee.swf"), loaderContext);
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the loadee.swf is not copyrighted material, you can add bytecodes to it using flasm or if you were an expert you can do it using any HEX editor.

P.S: Don't forget, Cross-Domain Policy is on port 843.

Comment: I just tested with a self-made loadee.swf and it threw the same error until I added Security.allowDomain("*"). You'd think Adobe would allow external swf's that are made with 3rd party applications to be loaded :O

Comment: Yes, of course. SWF is an open standard and you can load/modify SWF made by 3rd party applications like FlashDevelop for example. It needs high skills but it is possible.